# How to insert a payment related to an invoice via Odoo API RPC [Odoo11] [python]?

Tags: python, xml-rpc, odoo-11

I'm trying to create a payment related to an invoice via XML RPC (Odoo11) and I can't figure how. Can you give me an example of a payment insertion via XML RPC ?  Which method should I call & with what arguments ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

After a long search I found how to do it. I put you here the solution if it can help someone in the future

```
def create_payment(odoo, vals, invoice_id):
"""
Create payment line
:param odoo: odoo client
:param vals: amount, pay_date
:param invoice_id: id of invoice
:return:
"""
mod = odoo.env['account.payment']
id = mod.create(vals)
mod.browse(id).invoice_ids = [invoice_id]
mod.browse(id).post()
```

I also put the code to create a full invoice under odoo 11 with payment.
[here](https://gist.github.com/oxydedefer/9e2d135ac69d72c54facfba5c36cfa00)